# Mysql error message:"#1044 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' to database 'information_schema' " when trying to delete a table view

Tags: mysql, view, error-handling

I would like to know how to handle this error error "#1044 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' to database 'information_schema' " in order to delete a table view in a Mysql database. The explanation is as below:

I have a database called "wkayetdb" which contains a table view called "v_eventgroup". In order to delete that table view, I executed this SQL request:

```
SELECT VIEW_DEFINITION FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'wkayetdb' AND TABLE_NAME = 'v_eventgroup';
```

Then, after obtaining the result of the SQL request above and after clicking on the delete button to delete the view, I got this error message: **#1044 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' to database 'information_schema'**.
So, how can I handle this error?

Answer (score 0):

You need to either retrieve or reset the MYSQL password.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html